# Playing HD Video Android & iOS

Tags: android, video, mp4, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game (Unity 5.2) in which I need to play HD video (1280x800) at the start. That video is saved with the binary (apk/ipa). I tried following methods but none of them are working. My video is mp4, H.246 AAC codec.

```
    bool retVal = Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("myvideo.mp4");
```

Above line always returns true no matter if I give in correct file name or incorrect. Couldn't understand how this works.

I tried saving myvideo.mp4 file in `Assets/StreamingAssets` and directly under `Assets` folder.

I also tried to use MovieTexture but later found in documentation that its not available for Android.

Also, any highlights on which formats / resolutions are supports would be great.

A working example would be great.

Comment: Tried playing a video of size 190x240 and that plays fine. So is it that higher resolution videos cannot be played?

Comment: the unity docs say something about the limitation of ios  devices. but android doesn't work neither right?

Comment: I only tried android so far and its not working. Can you pls give me link to doc mentioning iOS limitations.

Comment: Just look up playFullscreenMovie in the docs search bar... http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.html

Comment: Ya, looks like unity is not a good choice for playing videos on mobile devices.